# How to compression image gif using gifsicle on command line?

Tags: linux, image, command-line, colors

How to compression image gif using gifsicle on command line ?

this is original_image.gif

```
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/is/151220085732.gif
```

And this original_image.gif info using code

```
gifsicle -I "#0" "#3" < ./public_html/original_image.gif
```

info

```
gifsicle: frame '#3' out of range, image has 1 frames
* <stdin> 1 image
  logical screen 1278x712
  global color table [256]
  background 255
  + image #0 1278x712 transparent 255
    comment Created with GIMP
    delay 0.20s
```

And this is original_image.gif size code

```
du -sch ./public_html/original_image.gif
```

size

```
372K    total
```

.

.

.

and this new_image.gif

```
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ii/151220085641.gif
```

And this new_image.gif info using code

```
gifsicle -I "#0" "#3" < ./public_html/new_image.gif
```

info

```
gifsicle: frame '#3' out of range, image has 1 frames
* <stdin> 1 image
  logical screen 1278x712
  global color table [256]
  background 242
  + image #0 1278x712 transparent 242
    comment Created with GIMP
    disposal asis delay 0.20s
```

And this is original_image.gif size code

```
du -sch ./public_html/new_image.gif
```

size

```
152K    total
```

.

.

.

i tried to use this code (`command line linux putty`) for compression original_image.gif to new_image.gif

```
gifsicle -b --colors=32 --scale 1.0 --use-col=web ./public_html/giphy.gif
```

and i got bad image result

```
http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/is/151220091120.gif
```

info

```
gifsicle: frame '#3' out of range, image has 1 frames
* <stdin> 1 image
  logical screen 1278x712
  global color table [32]
  background 1
  + image #0 1278x712 transparent 1
    comment Created with GIMP
    delay 0.20s
```

size

```
92K     total
```

How can i do for get best image compression like `new_image.gif` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "but not work"? What does that mean? You get no image? You get an error? Nothing happens?

Comment: Well, the result looks like the same image, only much more compressed. What is the issue with that? I mean that the quality is reduced is to be expected, `gif` uses a compression scheme that reduces quality. The more aggressively you compress, the lower the image quality you get.